C++ NRVO in the presence of multiple return points
I have the following C++ code that returns a std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>>. My question is about copy elision and named return value optimisation. As I understand, since C++-17, the standard mandates that the return value will be copy-elided. So no temporary tuple will be created and then, (I assume) std::tie will directly initialise list1, list2. Now, whether it will call a copy or move constructor for the vectors or allocate space before function call and directly use that space depends on whether NRVO is performed. I would like to know whether NRVO is performed in this case, and if not, how I can change the code to achieve a single vector allocation for both lists (without passing them in as parameters).
std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> parseInput(const std::string &filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Error: could not open file.\n";
        std::exit(1);
    }

    std::vector<int> list1, list2;
    int num1, num2;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> num1) {
            if (iss >> num2) {
                list1.push_back(num1);
                list2.push_back(num2);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error: Line only contains one number. Exiting.\n";
                std::exit(1);
            }
        } else {
            std::cerr << "Warning: Line contains no numbers. Skipping.\n";
        }
    }
    
    return {list1, list2};
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    std::vector<int> list1, list2;
    std::tie(list1, list2) = parseInput(f);
    ...
}


I tried to view this in Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/oxP1z5c3a). As far as I can tell, neither copy elision nor NRVO is performed because the code for parseInput calls both vector and tuple constructors. I would like to understand why better, and know how to improve my code.
EDIT: The question was a bit unclear. There are two objects of interest here - the tuple and the vector. In my example, the tuple was only being allocated once because of RVO. But the vectors were being allocated twice and copied. It is possible to convert the move to a copy by replacing the return {list1, list2}; with return { std::move(list1), std::move(list2) } (suggested by @Jarod42). Another option (suggested by @Eljay) is to created a named tuple t in the beginning and return t. Here, NRVO will be performed and both the tuple and the vectors will only be allocated once. Here is a cleaned-up example showing this.

I would say return {std::move(list1), std::move(list2)}; to avoid the copy of the vector.

RVO only is mandatory, not NRVO. Btw add -Wnrvo to your gcc option to see when it does not performs NRVO. In your case, you build a tuple on the fly which is return: it's full mandatory RVO, not NRVO. The "issue" lies in the way you're constructing the vectors and tieing them.

NRVO is specially for return var;, not return {var1, var2};.

[OT] For usage, you might possibly use more compact /*const*/auto [list1, list2] = parseInput(f); (and get rid of std::vector<int> list1, list2;).

Thanks for your help @Jarod42 ! Yes, I understand that constructing the return tuple directly (for return {var1, var2}; is RVO and not NRVO). In this case, the tuple is only constructed once. I am interested in knowing whether it's possible to construct the vectors also only once (as opposed to the move solution you mentioned).

I am interested in knowing whether it's possible to construct the vectors also only once std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<int>> result; and then later return result;  You can also auto& list1 = result.first; for example, to keep the rest of the code the same.

@Oersted - yes I understand that the tuple part is mandatory RVO. I am interested in whether the vector construction can also be optimised to be a single allocation instead of copying/moving the local vectors. I am a bit unaware about std::tie and how it works so may be missing some stuff.

Offtopic: Please do not use std::tuple in regular code. std::tuple is great when writing generic code. In this case it makes code harder to read and maintain. Defining simple stuct is much more reader friendly.

Ah I see. Thanks @Elijay, trying this out.

Offtopic: Why you are returning two vectors of ints? Why not return one vector of some struct containing two int fields. Based on code this should be more memory/cache friendly.

Cleaned Up Example - Created a cleaned up example to showcase this case. It seems like NRVO is performed in this case.

@MarekR Hmm, that is a good question, I didn't think of that actually. I agree this would be more memory friendly, thank you! Regarding std::tuple and readability, I am curious actually what would be more readable. I too dislike working with std::tuple objects. So, in something like the cleaned up example, what would you suggest is a better way to write it (the explicit construction from two named vectors would require moving the vectors)?

Here is my cleanup of first version: https://godbolt.org/z/qdE8n73PT

@RamneetSingh I would go with your "cleaned up example". You can also enable optimizations to make the assembly simpler, and optionally disable inlining to prove that only a single constructor of std::tuple (and therefore of both its vectors) is called: https://godbolt.org/z/E65zrExej.

Thanks @DanielLangr! For the record, auto [v1, v2] = getVec() also only allocates once (https://godbolt.org/z/h6d1acWvn). Small doubt about the generated assembly: could you please explain what variables rsp and rsp+4 refer to in the getVec() function body (after the initial pushes)? I'm trying to understand the stack layout but getting a little confused.

@MarekR Understood your point about using the struct. Thanks!

@RamneetSingh It just seems to be a temporary storage for some value that needs to be preserved through function calls. If you enable inlining, it disappears.

"Mandated RVO" is a misnomer. It is either mandated or optimisation. Optimisations are optional by their very nature.
